# Not able to connect to MS Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm

Unable to connect to CRM: Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Organization.OrganizationDetail.get_EnvironmentId()'.

This exception appears on 2 computers, but third computer ran developed utility without this error. Versions of Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll (v. 9.0.0002.0165) are equal on all of computers. I've already tried to add this library to GAC but it didn't help.

Code:

var client = new CrmServiceClient($@"AuthType=ClientSecret;url={organizationUri};ClientId={clientId};ClientSecret={clientSecret}");

Comment: If I'm not mistaken: if you would format the code you posted, it would look as if you want two lines, but the result is only one (invalid) line: `var client = new CrmServiceClient($@"AuthType=ClientSecret;url={organizationUri};ClientId={clientId};ClientSecret={clientSecret}");` because the first semicolon ;is in the middle of a "quoted string"

Answer (score 0):

This error: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Organization.OrganizationDetail.get_EnvironmentId()
indicated that your version of Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll is very out of date (that property was added back in 2019),

to fix it,
Update (from Nuget)
Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly

and

Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies -
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies

to current versions and recompile.

That should resolve the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn`t help. Error still appears.

Comment: Can you try this in a standalone console app?  I wonder if you project has other uses of xrm.sdk.dll and it’s dragging an older copy from another reference